# define multiple results all at the same time in php

Tags: php, smarty

I have `$config` variable that have arrays inside it. In smarty I assign the variable like this:

```
$smarty->assign('config', $config);
```

when I call it, I used this : `{$config.wateverarrayyouwant}`
now I want to do the same thing with php. I want to `define` them in the same manner. How can I define all the arrays in `$config` in just one line? 
I only know how to define a variable one at a time by using this :

```
define('wateverarrayyouwant', $config['wateverarrayyouwant']);
```

I tried changing wateverarrayyouwant to a variable because it can be any array :

```
define('$wateverarrayyouwant', $config[$wateverarrayyouwant]);
```

but the code above does not work. what is a good way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a `define` for each key value pair in the array you can use:

```
<?php
foreach($config as $key => $value) {
    define($key, $value);
}
```

I will note however that you cannot `define` array values, all [`define`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)'s must be scalar:

> The value of the constant; only scalar and null values are allowed. Scalar values are integer, float, string or boolean values.

If you check the OP's answer for further explanation of what he's trying to achieve, it can be done with:

```
<?php
foreach($config as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: not what i wanted, but you certainly deserve +1 for your answer.

Comment: Haha, thanks!  So what are you wanting, as I'm not quite sure now. =]

Comment: now I am thinking about it, I do not think it is possible.. I do not really need to explain.. I will just delete the question.

Comment: @shnisaka No need to delete the question - create an answer that explains why what you want to do is not possible, and select that as an answer so someone else searching for something similar will know why it can't be done. ^^

Answer (score 1):

This question cannot be done. because I am trying to define a variable as a constant. I was just thinking about how can I reduce the letters for variables and never though that I better leave them alone. Logically, why do somebody need to change `$config[$wateverarrayyouwant]` to `wateverarrayyouwant`. I was only thinking about maintaining a neat code. but now I am thinking about it.. it is better to leave it as it is : `$config[$wateverarrayyouwant]`

This can be done with:

```
foreach($config as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value;
}
```

Comment: Oh!  If you're trying to make them their own variables, that can be done! `$$key = $value;` inside the `foreach` loop!

Comment: Edited both answers since I forgot an edit here had to be approved by peer review. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You may not even want to use define here. `define` is used to create [`constants`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) not plain variables and that carries with it certain connotations:

- they are immutable for the life of the script
- they must be scalar

If you just want an array variable then define it like normal with:

```
$whatever = array(
  'key1' => 'value1'
);
```

Comment: He already knows how to make an array, that's what he is passing to Smarty ;)  I think he is wanting to make the config's either constant (which, depending on what you consider a configuration variable, is true).  OR, he is wanting them to be global or super-global.  Super global can't happen as those are reserved, but the other option would be to assign it to `$GLOBALS['config'] = $config;`